# how come sharpdevelop already has a version for .net 4.5?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, sharpdevelop

please see this link: http://build.sharpdevelop.net/buildartefacts/#SD45

i don't think they have published .net 4.5 yet, have they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a branch in preparation so that we can get started as soon as we get the .NET 4.5 bits (I think that there will be a beta release published at the Build conference).

But at the moment, that branch is not using .NET 4.5 yet; it's identical to 4.2 (except for the version number).

`async`/`await` support for code completion is already on the 4.2 branch.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to *guess*, this would refer to the language changes (`async`/`await`) in the async CTP, which is [available for download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9983) from Microsoft. However, it would be better to *ask them*.

Comment: oh, but guessing is so much fun! :)

Comment: I recall a mention of .net 4.5 runtime in upcoming windows 8 beta. May be that is what its aim for? Again, just a guess!